# Filtering by Child Div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter div elements by looking at the id of a child element, however I can't seem to get it working and can't spot why.

the html:

```
<div class="section-link" id="section-tooltip">
    <div class="brand tp" style="display: none;"></div>
    contents
</div>

<div class="section-link" id="section-tooltip">
    <div class="brand garden" style="display: none;"></div>
    contents
</div>
```

The js:

```
function brand(string){
    var brand = string;
    $('.section-link').hide();
    if ($(".section-link").children('.brand').hasClass(brand)) {
        $(this).parent().show();
    }
}
```

I am then executing the following via chrome browser: javascript:brand("tp");

it hides all the div's however it does not show the one with the tp element inside

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Thanks, that would be the issue

Comment: have swapped the id and the class over for the brand element, will test it now and see

Comment: Your edit seems to be worse. Now both the outer divs and inner divs share IDs.

Comment: Are you not getting errors on the console regarding hasclass? It should be hasClass instead.

Comment: does it not matter if its looking inside a div's child elements?

Comment: well when you use the `children` method it usually only looks at elements directly below, otherwise if you want to look through children, grand-children, great grand-children, etc. you should use the find() function instead

Comment: yeah no, that is wrong hey, no two elements should have the same id, the jquery will not work if that is so

Comment: I see, okay please see edit again

Comment: check my edit, have you tried my solution yet @SimonStaton ?

Answer (score 2):

$("this") is wrong.

```
$(this) //this is right
```

Edit. Another one:
it isn't

```
.hasclass()
```

but

```
.hasClass()
```

Comment: Okay fixed this too, still no luck :)

Comment: dammit! I shoulda typed a shorter answer. you win

Comment: @pythonian29033 - no one's 'won' yet since the OP's issues still exist.

Comment: Another one, it isn't  "hasclass" but "hasClass"... I'm going to edit the comment ;)

Comment: I just notice that the second part was still reported. My bad

Answer (score 2):

this piece of code:

```
if ($(".section-link").children('.brand').hasClass(brand)) {
   $("this").parent().show();
}
```

should be change to this:

```
$(".section-link").children('.brand').each(function(){
   if($(this).find(brand).length > 0){

      $(this).find(brand)[0].parent().show(); //assuming onlt the first 'tp's parent needs to be shown
   }
});
```

PS: this needs no enclosing quotes